Inconsisten behavior of the YouTube javascript api on iphone
in the Webflow site doing very standard implementation of YouTube video popup:
        const player = new YT.Player(playerSpot, {
          width: '640',
          videoId: popover.dataset.ytId,
          playerVars: {
            autoplay: false,
            playsinline: 1,
            color: 'white',
            rel: 0,
          },
          events: {
           onReady: function(ev) {
            ev.target.playVideo()
           }
         }
        });


for an unclear reason in 50% of cases the video does not start playing automatically and requires another click.
The playerSpot is an element with popover attribute.
The issue only occurs on iOs=^17, not on android or even iphone xcode simulator.
any idea can help.
the example page is here
